# How does one verify ipyparallel clients/engines?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, cluster-computing

I don't know how to get the context within which ipyparallel clients/engines are running.

I am setting up six Raspberry Pi computers in an IPython cluster that I'm accessing through Jupyter notebook. (Each Raspberry has four cores, so i set up 24 engines total.) Did I set things up correctly? Is the work distributed across all the Raspberries? I see 24 clients...

So, I tried this:

```py
import os
from ipyparallel import Client
rc = Client(profile='parallel')
rc[:].map(lambda x: os.system('hostname'))
```

But it complained:

AssertionError: must have some sequences to map onto!

I expect someone smarter than me will say, "do X, to get output like this":

```sh
raspi2a (repeated 4 times...)
raspi2b
raspi3a
raspi4a
raspi4b
raspi4c
```

Comment: With all the respect to your professional knowledge, could you also confirm, that your have setup ( and verified an unobstructed online "visibility" ) in all the IPython's distributed infrastructure configuration JSON-files and using feasible port-configurations, contained therein? What gets printed upon a call to **`rc.ids`** ?

Comment: (Thank you for asking.) When i replace the last line of my code with rc.ids i get a vector of integers from 0 to 23.